# for для прохождение всех списков в списке (Python)

Tags: python, list

Есть функция проверки победителя, которая вызывается из другой функции, при прохождение цикла for берется только 1 список из всех, а остальные не прогоняет. Не могу разобраться почему

```py
box = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
win_combination = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9), (1, 5, 9), (3, 5, 7)]


def check_winner():
    for i in win_combination: # В ЭТОМ МЕСТЕ ОН БЕРЕТ ТОЛЬКО ПЕРВЫЙ СПИСОК ИЗ ВСЕХ(1, 2, 3)
        print(win_combination)
        print(i)
        if (box[i[0] - 1]) == (box[i[1] - 1]) == (box[i[2] - 1]):
            return box[i[1] - 1]
        else:
            return False


if count > 3:
    winner = check_winner()
    if winner:
        paint_box()
        return print(winner + " Выиграл")
        break
    count += 1
```

Comment: потому что потом у вас return стоит в цикле

Comment: А что нужно сделать тогда?

Comment: Убрать лишнюю табуляцию у `else: return False` например

Comment: Всем спасибо!!!

Comment: @Hellius, оформите тогда, пожалуйста, сами решение проблемы как свой ответ и после примите его :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def check_winner():
    for i in win_combination:
        if (box[i[0] - 1]) == (box[i[1] - 1]) == (box[i[2] - 1]):# Условие проверки одинаковые ли 3 символа
            return box[i[0] - 1]
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).